# change color of page number on a single page

Tags: color, page-numbering, pagecolor

I am coloring a single page of my document black (`\pagecolor{black}`) but need the page number on the bottom to be in white text.  What's the simplest/best way to do this, ideally without importing any packages or complicated custom commands?

Comment: You could define a new page style which colours the page number and load it only for the wanted page with `\thispagestyle`

Comment: it depends on how you add the page number. So make a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Easiest would be to use the etoolkit package to modify `\ps@plain` (or whatever page style you are using) to replace `\thepage` with your own macro (which would change the color).

Comment: I just put \pagenumbering{arabic} in my main file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not referencing any page numbers and have an elementary document, you can place a conditional within `\thepage`:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=3
    \textcolor{white}{3}%
  \else
    \textcolor{black}{\arabic{page}}%
  \fi}
```

Here's a complete, minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,afterpage}

\newcommand{\thispagecolor}[1]{\pagecolor{#1}\afterpage{\pagecolor{white}}}

%\pagenumbering{arabic}
% Set page 3 with a white page number
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=3
    \textcolor{white}{3}%
  \else
    \textcolor{black}{\arabic{page}}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]% This runs on to page 3

\thispagecolor{black}% Turn this page (page 3) black

\lipsum[16-30]% This runs on to page 6

\end{document}
```

If you want to reference that page, you are better off adding the conditional to whatever page style you may be running (`plain` by default); easiest here is to use [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{% Center footer
    \ifnum\value{page}=3
      \textcolor{white}{3}%
    \else
      \textcolor{black}{\thepage}%
    \fi}
}
\pagestyle{plain}% Initiate above changes
```

Better yet it to specify your own page style for that non-conforming page:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{whitepagenum}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}% Center footer
}

...

\thispagecolor{black}%
\thispagestyle{whitepagenum}%

...
```